# Winapi c++ make static image behave like a button (Hover, Click)

Tags: c++, windows, image, winapi, hover

I want to change a Static bitmap image when hovering it. I've tried using a button instead, but the picture never fill the button. I've tried too TrackMouseEvent but I want it to be always active so i cannot use this. Is there a way to get notified when mouse hover a static control  or to make a control that behaves like that?

This is my control:

```
HWND Button = CreateWindow("Static", NULL,
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | SS_BITMAP | SS_NOTIFY,
        20, 240, 120, 20,
        hwnd, (HMENU)101, NULL, NULL);
SendMessage(hwnd, STM_SETIMAGE, (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)view.vBitMap);
```

I use SS_NOTIFY nto get notified when user clicks it or doubleclicks it, but unlike BS_NOTIFY, it don't tell when hovering on WM_NOTIFY

Comment: *"I've tried too TrackMouseEvent but I want it to be always active so i cannot use this."* - Why would `TrackMouseEvent` (which happens to be *the* solution) not work for you?

Comment: TrackMouseEvent needs to be activated for a period of time, but I need it to always send hovering notifications

Comment: Hovering, by definition, is only triggered, when the mouse is over a window and hasn't been moved for some time. If you aren't looking for hovering, don't ask for hovering. You really want to handle the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message to deduce, when the mouse pointer enters your window, and set up `WM_MOUSELEAVE` notifications using `TrackMouseEvent`, the get notified, when the mouse leaves your window.